# Conditional ItemsControl.ItemTemplate binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a project and as redundant as it is - I'm trying to do it entirely without code-behind.

I have a User Control called MessagePanel that's meant to wrap messages received through the TCP connection.

Messages can either be text-only or image-only and my control is meant to handle both using different data templates.

Template for texts:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Template for images:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'm having an issue figuring out how to trigger for either of them to be used based on a `IsImage` boolean property.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: ItemsControl has an [ItemTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=netframework-4.7.2) property for exactly this use case. Besides that, you can also add a DataTrigger on the IsImage to the Triggers collection of a single DataTemplate, which sets the Visibility of the UI elements in the DataTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, the second options sounds more like my niche, because then I can keep the data templates inside the element and won't have to make a separate ItemTemplateSelector class.

Comment: @Clemens Could you post an answer? The one you've put in the comments - so I can mark as the answer and we can increase the database for others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, and you would typically use a `DataTemplateSelector` that is assigned to the ItemsControl's `Item​Template​Selector` property.

You may however write a XAML-only solution with a DataTrigger in the `ItemContainerStyle` of the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that you might probably not need to have an `IsImage` property. The DataTrigger could as well check the `Image` property for `null`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
```